# gksudo and python script

Tags: python, gksudo

Hi I have a smaller problem now but a problem nonetheless. My python script seems to execute out of order when it is run via gksudo. The system commands in the first if block execute before,

```
print ("Removing Partial, Unneeded, And Obsolete Packages...");
```

that line.

Here is the rest of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os;

F1 = open('/tmp/F1.txt', 'r').read();
F2 = open('/tmp/F2.txt', 'r').read();
F3 = open('/tmp/F3.txt', 'r').read();
F4 = open('/tmp/F4.txt', 'r').read();
F5 = open('/tmp/F5.txt', 'r').read();
os.system("rm /tmp/F1.txt");
os.system("rm /tmp/F2.txt");
os.system("rm /tmp/F3.txt");
os.system("rm /tmp/F4.txt");
os.system("rm /tmp/F5.txt");


if F1=="1":
    print ("Removing Partial, Unneeded, And Obsolete Packages...");
    os.system ("sudo apt-get clean -y -f");
    os.system ("sudo apt-get autoremove -y -f");
    os.system ("sudo apt-get autoclean -y -f");
    open('/tmp/Point.txt', 'w').write("2");
    print ("...Done");

if F2=="1":
    print ("Clearing Temporary Files...");
    os.system ("sudo rm -rf /tmp/*");
    open('/tmp/Point.txt', 'w').write("3");
    print ("...Done");

if F3=="1":
    print ("Clearing Unused Thumbnails...");
    os.system ("rm -f ~/.thumbnails/normal/*");
    open('/tmp/Point.txt', 'w').write("4");
    print ("...Done");

if F4=="1":
    print ("Clearing Downloads Folder...");
    os.system ("rm -r ~/Downloads/*");
    open('/tmp/Point.txt', 'w').write("5");
    print ("...Done");

if F5=="1":
    print ("Emptying Trash...");
    os.system ("rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*");
    open('/tmp/Point.txt', 'w').write("6");
    print ("...Done");

print ("");
os.system("rm /tmp/Point.txt"); 
print ("Cleanup Complete.");
```

Please help A.S.A.P.,
Brooks Rady.

Answer (score 1):

While this is merely a guess, I expect what you're seeing is a result of [I/O buffering](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html). If this is in Python 3.3 or later, try [`print(message, flush=True)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). In Python 2, you'll need to call [`sys.stdout.flush()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) - but it will only happen if stdout is not determined to be a terminal; for instance if run by cron, or piped to another program. To demonstrate the issue, run the script:

```
import time, sys

print "hello there"
#sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print "bye"
```

If run using `python script`, it works just fine, but if run as `python script | dd bs=1` nothing will show until the two seconds pass, at which point both printed lines appear. Removing the `#`, so that the flush occurs, fixes this issue.

The reason for this I/O buffering is to collect lots of small prints, reducing the number of calls to external I/O. It's rarely a noticeable difference, but can eventually matter, for instance with memories that wear out or I/O devices with fixed block sizes. The `dd` command I used to show the difference does buffering with configurable parameters, in this case 1 byte.

Incidentally, all the semicolons in your script are unnecessary.

Comment: I thought that would help, but unfortunately my problem persists. Any ideas?